# Pass function argument to defined variable

Tags: bash, variable, function, arguments

How can I "inject" a function argument to a defined variable like in this example?

```
mood="i am $1 happy"

happy ()
{
    echo "$mood"
}

happy "very"
```

Current output:

```
i am  happy
```

Desired output:

```
i am very happy
```

Thanks!

**Edit**:

The real world example is: I have a lot of translatable strings in another file, like so:

```
installing="Installing"
installation_started="The installation of <app> started at <date>"
installation_ended="The installation of <app> ended at <date>"
```

And a function:

```
apt_get_install ()
{
    echo "$installing $1..."
    echo "$installation_started"
    apt-get -y install "$1"
    echo "$installation_ended"
}

apt_get_install <app>
```

And then I want to inject `<app>` to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Be very careful with `eval`, never use `eval` on user input, it will execute anything.

```
mood='i am $1 happy'

happy ()
{
    eval echo "$mood"
}

happy "very"
```

Comment: Thanks, I try to avoid using `eval` but your answer solves the problem. Accepted.

Comment: That means `eval` ends up evaluating `echo i am $1 happy` where `$1` is not quoted. You'd want: `eval "echo \"$mood\""`. So we end up evaluating `echo "i am $1 happy"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to provide informational messages to a user in various languages.  You should probably use software specifically designed for this purpose, if you want to do it right.  In the GNU world, there is [`gettext`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) that may be of use to you. (It is not a trivial problem to solve!)

The text below addresses the question before its update, and part of the updated question (before I noticed that it was about providing translated messages):

---

Your example does not make much sense as your function is just an alias for `echo`.  You can easily call your `happy` function as

```
happy "I am $adjective happy"   # $adjective would be the string "very"
```

Apart from that, it sounds like the standard `printf` function could also be useful to know about:

```
adjective='very'
printf 'I am %s happy\n' "$adjective"
```

`printf` take one or more arguments, where the first is a *static* string describing the output format, possibly containing placeholders, and the rest of the arguments are referenced by the placeholders.

---

If the messages are static format strings, then just use `printf`:

```
apt_get_install ()
{
    printf 'Installing %s...\n' "$1"
    printf '%s installation started at %s\n' "$1" "$(date)"
    apt-get -y install "$1"
    printf '%s installation ended at %s\n' "$1" "$(date)"
}

apt_get_install thing
```

Related:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

Comment: Thanks, it will take me some time to digest your updated answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
function happy ()
{
        mood="i am $1 happy"
        echo "$mood"
}

happy "very"
```

Or Try the below one,

```
function happy ()
{
        echo "i am $1 happy"
}

happy "very"
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can not have the variable inside the function.

Comment: Why not? Aside from this, you don't need a variable in this concrete example. You can expand the `$1` inside the `echo` command.

Comment: I edited the post with a real world example.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
mood='I am $1 happy'

happy () {
  printf '%s\n' ${(e)mood}
}

happy very
```

The `e` parameter expansion flags causes all the parameter expansions, arithmetic expansions and command substitutions to be evaluated in the content of the variable (backslash in front of the `$` or `` ` `` can be used to prevent them).

Another approach that avoids dangerous things like the `e` or `eval` is to use `gettext`'s `envsubst`, where you can specify exactly  what you want substituted:

```
mood='I am $HOWMUCH happy'
happy() {
  HOWMUCH=$1 envsubst <<< "$mood"
}
happy very
```

Though `<<<` is also a zsh extension, it is now supported by a few other shells including `bash`.

Replace `envsubst` with `envsubst '$HOWMUCH'` if you want to make sure that only `$HOWMUCH` (or `${HOWMOUCH}`) gets substituted.

With `ksh93` or `zsh`, you can also use:

```
mood='I am %1$s happy\n'
happy() {
  printf "$mood" "$@"
}
```

In other `printf` implementations that don't support the `%1$s` to specify which argument to use, in this particular case, you can use `%s`. If the format has `%s %s`, the first `%s` gets the first argument, the second the second argument. You can use `%2$s %1$s` to reverse the order with `ksh93` or `zsh`. In other implementations, you could use this trick  instead:

```
case $(locale language) in
  (*English*) msg="I am in a %s %s%.0s%.0s\n";     mood=mood;;
  (*French*)  msg="Je suis d'une %.0s%s %s%.0s\n"; mood=humeur;;
esac

mood() {
  printf "$msg" "$@" "$@"
}

mood formidable "$mood"
```

Which would print `I'm in a formidable mood` to an English-speaking user and `Je suis d'une humeur formidable` to a French-speaking user. We pass the arguments twice and use `%.0s` (the string truncated to zero width) to discard the ones we don't want to be able to use those arguments in different orders.